# Find value of $\lim_{m \to \infty} \int _0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} f(x+2)}{2^mx^2 + 2^{-m}} dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral

The problem I'm working on is as follows. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous. Prove that the following limit $$\lim_{m \to \infty} \int _0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} f(x+2)}{2^mx^2 + 2^{-m}} dx$$ exists and find it.

Here are my ideas for the solution: Since $f(x)$ is bounded, we know that there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M < \infty$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, we have:
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \int _0^\infty \frac{e^{-x} f(x+2)}{2^mx^2 + 2^{-m}} dx = M \lim_{m \to \infty} \int _0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{2^mx^2 + 2^{-m}} dx.$$
I think I need to use either the Dominated Convergence Theorem or the Monotone Convergence Theorem to show that I can swap the limit and integral; however, I am having trouble finding an upper bound on the integrand or showing that it is monotone. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the crucial question is what is this limit $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty}I_m= \frac{1}{2^m}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+2^{-2m}}dx$.

Let $x=2^{-m}y$.  Then $I_m=\int_0^{2^m}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}$ which converges.

Comment: After taking some more time on this, I'm a little confused by what you mean. Did you mean to define $I_m = \frac{1}{2^m} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+2^{-2m}}\ dx$, which would imply that $\lim_{m \to \infty} I_m = \lim_{m\to \infty}  \frac{1}{2^m} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2+2^{-2m}}\ dx$. If so, I'm not sure how this lets us use DCT since we don't have an upper bound that is not dependent on $m$. Showing that $\lim_{m \to \infty} I_m < \infty$ doesn't let us apply DCT or MCT. Am I missing an important piece or theorem? Thank you!

Comment: After the change of variables $x=2^{-m}y$, the integrand $\frac{1}{1+y^2}$ where $0\le y \le 2^m$ and $0$ otherwise  is dominated by $\frac{1}{1+y^2}$  for $0\le y \lt \infty$.